# SpacebrewYun: undefined reference to `Console'

Tags: arduino, compilador

Estoy tratando de utilizar la placa Arduino Yún con uno de los ejemplos ([*spacebrewBoolean*](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/SpacebrewYun/blob/master/examples/spacebrewBoolean/spacebrewBoolean.ino)) que tiene la misma libreria, pero al hacerlo no puedo compilar el codigo que viene en el ejemplo, que podrá ser? Me regresa los siguientes errores:

> Arduino:1.6.13 (Windows 8.1), Tarjeta:"Arduino Yún"
>
> C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTknPM9.ltrans1.ltrans.o: In function `main':
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans1.o:(.text.startup+0x696): undefined reference to `Console'
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans1.o:(.text.startup+0x698): undefined reference to `Console'
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans1.o:(.text.startup+0x69a): undefined reference to `ConsoleClass::read()'
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans1.o:(.text.startup+0x6c0): undefined reference to `Console'
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans1.o:(.text.startup+0x6c2): undefined reference to `Console'
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans1.o:(.text.startup+0x6c4): undefined reference to `ConsoleClass::available()'
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans1.o:(.text.startup+0xab0): undefined reference to `Console'
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans1.o:(.text.startup+0xab2): undefined reference to `Console'
>
> C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTknPM9.ltrans2.ltrans.o: In function `SpacebrewYun::connect(String, >int) [clone .constprop.38]':
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans2.o:(.text+0x88a): undefined reference to `Console'
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans2.o:(.text+0x88c): undefined reference to `Console'
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans2.o:(.text+0x88e): undefined reference to `ConsoleClass::begin()'
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans2.o:(.text+0x8ba): undefined reference to `Console'
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans2.o:(.text+0x8bc): undefined reference to `Console'
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans2.o:(.text+0x8be): undefined reference to `ConsoleClass::connected()'
>
> C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTknPM9.ltrans2.ltrans.o: In function `SpacebrewYun::send(String >const&, String const&) [clone .constprop.34]':
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans2.o:(.text+0xa06): undefined reference to `Console'
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans2.o:(.text+0xa08): undefined reference to `Console'
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans2.o:(.text+0xa10): undefined reference to `Console'
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans2.o:(.text+0xa12): undefined reference to `Console'
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans2.o:(.text+0xa1a): undefined reference to `Console'
>
> C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTknPM9.ltrans2.ltrans.o:ccTknPM9.ltrans2.o:(.text+0xa1c): more >undefined references to `Console' follow
>
> C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTknPM9.ltrans2.ltrans.o: In function `SpacebrewYun::send(String >const&, String const&) [clone .constprop.34]':
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans2.o:(.text+0xa3a): undefined reference to `ConsoleClass::flush()'
>
> C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Temp\ccTknPM9.ltrans2.ltrans.o: In function `global constructors keyed to >65535_0_spacebrewBoolean.ino.cpp.o.2895':
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans2.o:(.text.startup+0x1b8): undefined reference to `Console'
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans2.o:(.text.startup+0x1ba): undefined reference to `Console'
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans2.o:(.text.startup+0x1bc): undefined reference to `ConsoleClass::begin()'
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans2.o:(.text.startup+0x26a): undefined reference to `Console'
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans2.o:(.text.startup+0x26c): undefined reference to `Console'
>
> ccTknPM9.ltrans2.o:(.text.startup+0x26e): undefined reference to `ConsoleClass::buffer(unsigned char)'
>
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> exit status 1
>   Error compilación en tarjeta Arduino Yún.

Comment: Hola drivit y bienvenido. Es error de compilación? Si el código no es muy extenso , podrías añadirlo?